# LOOKUP not working for a simple example in Excel. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, lookup

I have a list of scores. I want to convert them to a new score based on a table I have. I am tried using lookup and vlookup and I can't get it to work. What I am doing wrong?

Here is a link to the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18q-hV4SBD_WPQYXhdYpzgurQhe5xxRWmD8akCDrnhQo/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using LOOKUP the lookup values need to be sorted in ascending order.

Use VLOOKUP with `FALSE` as the forth criterion, to force an exact match:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,$D$3:$E$93,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it had to be ascending order.

I messed around with vlookup. Still not sure what I was doing wrong, but this works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GIve Headings in Row 1 As :
Name,Score 1,Score 2,Score 3
Enter Any Seven Names In A2 to A8

In B2:B8 the Score is :Say 48,75,65,85,35,84,46

In C2:C8 the score is already generated by the formula which I am explaining Now For the Score Test 3 : Say 85,62,47,63,39,50,59

Our Latest Score Card is always to be placed in the Area : A13 To B20 where
A13 is Title : " Name " ; B13 is Tilted as "Score 3" Say
In A14 to A20 All above 7 Names and In B14 to B20 Latest Marks

THE TABLE OF LATEST SCORE A13 To B20  HAS **TO BE SORTED ON NAME**
Because It is to be used for **VLOOKUP**

Now In Cell D2 Enter the Formula As Below :

=VLOOKUP($A2,$A$14:$B$20,2)
Copy this Formula From D3 To D8

So That Gives the Score Card 3

Before Entring Score Card 4 Marks in The TABLE Do;

1. First Copy D1:D8 And Paste It To E1:E8
2. Now Copy D1:D8 and Paste Values in Same Area D1:D8
3. Enter the 4th Score Card In Areas A13 To B20
4. Sort It On the Names.
5. YOu Get Score Column For 4th Test.

I hope, though it has become little clumsy, it serves the purpose.

THANKS.